# XmlReader on Android

Tags: c#, android

I have a problem with my XmlReader.
The thing is that reader is reading webpage only 2 times, but i need a little more..
If I call my reader from method :

```
public string Meth1()
    {
        string tvcal = "";
        string url = "http://www.nbrb.by/Services/XmlExRates.aspx?ondate=" + dtp1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name.Equals("Currency"))
            {
                reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
                try
                {
                    if (Int32.Parse(reader.Value) == 145)
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("CharCode");
                        currencyUSD = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Name");
                        currencyUSD += " " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Rate");
                        currencyUSD += " " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString() + " руб.\n";

                        tvcal += ("На Дату------" + dtp1.ToShortDateString() + "------\n");
                        tvcal += (currencyUSD);
                    }
                    if (Int32.Parse(reader.Value) == 19)
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("CharCode");
                        currencyEUR = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Name");
                        currencyEUR += " " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Rate");
                        currencyEUR += " " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString() + " руб.\n";

                        tvcal += (currencyEUR);
                    }
                    if (Int32.Parse(reader.Value) == 190)
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("CharCode");
                        currencyRUR = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Name");
                        currencyRUR += " " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Rate");
                        currencyRUR += " " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString() + " руб.\n";

                        tvcal += (currencyRUR);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        return tvcal;
    }
```

it is compiling, and everything is fine, then if I call it again it still works a returns me result.
But if i try to call it third time it brakes with no errors here:`while (reader.Read())`
Another problem with that reader hapend, when i try to call enother class to use reader in there.
Firs i call method `Meth1` in my class, it gives me result, then i call another class wich contains 2 methods like `Meth1`, they do the saim job, but for static date. And in the moment when compiling is coming to `while (reader.Read())` in the second method of other class (the third object of XmlReader) it sends hendle back to android application and it brakes after several seconds.

I have searched for such problem, but found nothing.
Another application, wich is running on Windows is working correctly with simmilar classes and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ensured you are reading your XML response correctly?

Try wrapping the XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url) statemnet into an using() - statement for disposement after you finished your processing.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped !)
such an easy way to solve that problem !)